# Using PHP Redis as Session Store

Tags: session, redis

I'm trying to use php-redis as the session store to my craftcms site.
What I've tried:

1. apt-get install php5-redis
2. Edited php.ini with the following:

   `session.save_handler = redis
   session.save_path = "tcp://redis:6379?auth=password”`

Still, I don't see any sessions saved in redis.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This may help:

Add the following to the general.php

```
'cacheMethod' => 'redis',
'overridePhpSessionLocation' => 'tcp://localhost:6379'
```

Add the following to the index.php

```
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'redis')
```

Comment: For some reason I can't see redis as a Registered save handler in phpinfo()
Any tip to overcome this?

Comment: Can you check if you got the following in the php.ini 

`[Session]
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://localhost:6379"
session.use_cookies = 1`

Also check if you are editing the right php.ini file "Loaded Configuration File" that is shown in phpinfo()